# datagrid row LostFocus event raises unhandled exception when delete, using caliburn micro only

Tags: wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro

I have a datagrid with LostFocus event on it's cells which works perfect except when deleting a row using the keyboard Delete button, it throws unhandled exception (ActionMessage.cs not found)...
HOWEVER when i create a xaml button outside the datagrid that performs the same as the keyboard delete button, the LostFocus event works perfect.

My question is this a bug or what?, because i've tried it with simple wpf with code behind no mvvm, and it works perfectly anyway.

Comment: What's the exact exception and stack trace?

Comment: the exact exception is "No target found for method OnCellLostFocus", the function works well when i change the focus from one cell to another but when deleting it throws that exception.
I think when i create a button outside the grid to delete, the LostFocus fires before the actual delete happens but when the delete button is pressed it deletes then fires up LostFocus hense something happens that cant find the target function :/